# Angular universal + nodeJs + express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, express

Muy buenas a todos. Tengo una duda sobre el uso de angular universal con una spa donde el front (Angular 5+) y el back (nodeJs + express) estén separados.

Por lo que he podido ver/leer en la documentación y buscando por la web, lo que se suele hacer es implementar un server dentro del proyecto de angular. Un server.ts
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no acabo de entender si han de coexistir dos aplicaciones de express, la de mi API y por otro lado la del proyecto de angular. O si no se puede utilizar angular universal si el back y el front no están juntos... alguien puede aclararme un poco esto y guiarme?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal es para renderear aplicaciones angular en el servidor.

Una aplicación normal en angular se ejecuta en el browser, renderea paginas en el DOM en repuesta para la acción del usuario. Angular universal se ejecuta en el server, y genera aplicaciones con paginas estáticas  luego obtiene bootstrapped en el client. Esto significa que la aplicación generalmente genera renders mas rápidos.

Este es un ejemplo de como funciona normalment
[image: Este es un ejemplo de como funciona normalmente]

Este es un ejemplo de como funciona con Angular Universal

[image: Este es un ejemplo de como funciona con Angular Universal]

Puedes leer mas sobre esto en https://angular.io/guide/universal